# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error whenever I run this:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

The Code:

```
$amn = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Messages` WHERE to_user='$usr' AND read='0'");
print_r(mysql_num_rows($amn));
```

Comment: Look to the right. Pick any one. This has been answered _many, many times_ before.

Comment: Seems like we're seeing more and more of these. At least 2-3/day over the last week.

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742239/php-mysql-error-warning-mysql-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resourc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428575/how-to-fix-this-warning-mysql-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource and .... ad nauseum

Comment: @Michael: Just more of the trend of Stack Overflow turning from "questions about programming languages" repository into some "fix my code please" discussion board. I think the concensus thus far has been, unfortunately, that all we can do about it is to continue wasting our time downvoting and closevoting.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything that  helps.

Comment: @user921489: Every single answer to every single duplicate question under "Related" helps. If you need clarification, write a comment... when you have gained enough rep through site participation to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because mysql_query sometimes returns boolean false (query error). You need to check it:

```
$amn = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Messages` WHERE to_user='$usr' AND read='0'");

if($amn === false) {
    var_dump(mysql_error());
}
else {
    print_r(mysql_num_rows($amn));
}
```

Code above is written in bad style and deprecated. Use PDO with Exceptions in real projects.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your mysql_query is returning false, probably because of the weird quotes on the "Messages" bit on your query.

Comment: "Weird quotes"? Those are backticks, and using them to delimit field names is _proper_.